# How to automatically generate unit testing routines from special syntax in method docstring / comment?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, docstring

This is a mock-up of what I'm looking for:

```py
def is_even(a, b):
    """Returns True if both numbers are even.
    @AutoUnitTestTag:
    - (0,2) -> True
    - (2,1) -> False
    - (3,5) -> False
    """
    return (a % 2 == 0 and b % 2 == 0)
```

Is there a tool that could allow one to insert compact syntax-defined unit tests within a function's docstring and then automatically generate a `unittest_foobar.py` unit testing routine?

I'm almost sure I've seen this a while ago, but cannot find it.

**EDIT**: @mkrieger1 suggested `doctest` in the comments below and after playing a bit with it, I'd say it's a pretty apt solution.
However, I'd like to let this question linger a bit longer in order to collect more suggestions, especially about more sophisticated tools.

If someone's interested, here's how one would use doctest in my example case:

1. Format function in file `is_even.py` like so:

```
def is_even(a,b):
    """Returns True if both numbers are even.
    >>> is_even(0,2)
    True
    >>> is_even(2,1)
    False
    >>> is_even(3,5)
    False
    """
    return (a % 2 == 0 and b % 2 == 0)
```

2. Then run the command `python3 -m doctest is_even.py`.
   The output will look like so:

```
Trying:
    is_even(0,2)
Expecting:
    True
ok
Trying:
    is_even(2,1)
Expecting:
    False
ok
Trying:
    is_even(3,5)
Expecting:
    False
ok
1 items had no tests:
    foo2
1 items passed all tests:
   3 tests in foo2.is_even
3 tests in 2 items.
3 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 > It's about half-way of what I mean. Syntax-wise, that's pretty close of what I'm looking for, but I haven't figured out how to generate proper tests with it. Might give it another try.

Comment: Ok, I've just played a bit with doctest and I might manage to pull it off with this. Might even post a solution this evening, but I'd like to know if there are more sophisticated tools laying around.

Comment: What do you mean by "more sophisticated"? What features are you missing?

Comment: @Thomas > I was looking for something that would generate an actual `unittest_mystuff.py` because it's what my colleague is looking for (I'm sure he can be persuaded to switch to doctest, though). AFAIC, doctest satisfies my requirement. At this point it's just me being curious as to whether there's a super-duper tool somewhere in the git-verse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) and it's part of the standard library. But you'll have to change your syntax a bit:

```
def is_even(a, b):
    """Returns True if both numbers are even.

    >>> is_even(0, 2)
    True
    >>> is_even(2, 1)
    False
    >>> is_even(3, 5)
    False
    """
    return (a % 2 == 0 and b % 2 == 0)
```

You can run it with:

```
python -m doctest is_even.py
```

The syntax has been designed so that you can mostly copy and paste your tests from an interactive (C)Python interpreter session, so there is good reason not to try and change it. Moreover, other Python developers will already be familiar with this syntax, and not with anything custom you might come up with.

Comment: Holy cow, we simultaneously posted the same code (I edited the question) :D . I'm upvoting your answer and will check it after a while if nothing else comes up.

Comment: Ok let's mark this submission as the answer. I'll just add that the doctest can be run in the terminal with this command : `python3 -m doctest is_even.py`. `is_even.py` being the file containing the code @Thomas provided.